# Javascript Get flat array from object contain multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to merge multiple arrays from one object using JavaScript(React-Native), the example of the object is :

```
{"10419": ["37046", "37047"], "9138": ["32809"]}
```

The result should be like so:

```
["37046","37047","32809"]
```

I need to ignore the object name and end up with only one flat array

I used `flat()` function but it seems not working as I need.

my try looks like :

```
    var obj = this.state.obj // will contain the object
    console.log(obj.flat()) // I know that work only with arrays but I tried it out
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
Object.values(this.state.obj).flat()
```

Answer (score 3):

- Using `Object.values`, you can get the values inside the object. That will be 2d array from your input.
- Using `Array.prototype.flat`, you can make it as 1d array as follows.

```js
const input = {"10419": ["37046", "37047"], "9138": ["32809"]}
const result = Object.values(input).flat();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Simon that depends on the browser, since object keys are not ordered.